# Is there any good desktop/application or command line tool to show two different timezone concurrently?

Tags: linux, time-zone, command-line-tool

I want to find a desktop application or command line tool to show two different timezone concurrently under **LINUX.**

Anyone knows there are such application?

Say i want to know the time at london and USA at the same time. (different time zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu 10.10 or previous version .

The GNOME clock applet can show two times in the drop down.

[image]

Right click on the clock and select "Preferences." Goto the "Locations" tab and press "add."

Then, select "whatever" from the "Timezone" list.

[image]

Comment: that's great, thx~

Comment: glad to help, anytime.

Comment: NB: You should have used London rather than Greenwich Mean Time. Given that the United Kingdom uses Daylight Saving Time, they are not always the same!

Answer (score 2):

At the command line, you could use:

```
watch "echo "Local Time: ";date;echo "";echo "GMT: ";date --utc"
```

Edit: Here's an example [taken from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29#Examples), showing how to use various Timezones:

```
OLDTZ=$TZ
export TZ=GMT; echo "GMT:               `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
GMT:               2008-10-31 12:30 (GMT)
export TZ=Europe/Stockholm; echo "Stockholm:    `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
Stockholm:    2008-10-31 13:30 (CET)
export TZ=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur; echo "Kuala Lumpur:        `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
Kuala Lumpur:        2008-10-31 20:30 (MYT)
export TZ=US/Central; echo "Dallas:             `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
Dallas:             2008-10-31 07:30 (CDT)
export TZ=$OLDTZ
```

Edit 2: Also, here's an example applying some of how @garyjohn suggested this be approached:

```
watch "echo "JST Time: ";TZ=JST date;echo "";echo "MET-1METDST: "; TZ=MET-1METDST date"
```

Comment: You could also get each entry you want on a single line by using "date"'s FORMAT specifying feature to include the label/title text.

Comment: that's awesome. but how can we use "date" to get a specific timezone date? say, GMT-7?

Comment: @Kit, Okay, I edited the answer to include examples of how to do that.

Comment: `export TZ=GMT-8; echo "GMT-8:    `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
GMT-8:    2011-07-19 01:27 (GMT)`

`export TZ=GMT+8; echo "GMT+8:    `date +\"%F %R (%Z)\"`"
GMT+8:    2011-07-18 09:27 (GMT)`

It is strange...GMT+8 and GMT-8, the time is reversal..

Answer (score 1):

You could launch a number of xclock instances from the command line or from a script like this, prefixing each command with the desired timezone (TZ) for that clock.

```
TZ=JST-9 xclock &
TZ=MET-1METDST xclock &
```

Those will give you the times in Japan and Germany. See the xclock(1) man page or execute

```
xclock -help
```

for more options.

Comment: oh cool~, but would there any option that can fix it on the desktop just like a google widget?

Comment: You can position them using the -geometry option, but xclock is just a normal X application--I don't think there is any way to embed it in your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what desktop environment you're using, but in KDE I just put a second clock applet on my taskbar panel.  You can set the timezone for each clock individually.

Comment: Well, say gnome 2.x, in fedora/ubuntu distribution

Comment: It [doesn't appear to be possible](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1526117) with the regular Gnome clock app in more recent versions, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kit Ho , if you are running Ubuntu 10.10 and below see my answer. If Ubuntu 11.04 @Chris he is right.